# ls: cannot access X: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04, ls, auto-completion

When I try to use the command "unzip " on any folder I immediately get the line

```
unzip ls: cannot access 'tmp': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'tmp': No such file or directory
^C
```

which is particularly weird to me, cause my alias

```
alias unpack='unzip'
```

works perfectly fine.
the unzip command still works, though cant be autocompleted.
The native "zip" command on the other hand can autocomplete just fine.

I tried "sudo apt reinstall bash-completion" with no difference.

EDIT 1:
I noticed this happens for other commands as well. Examples:

- type "java -", autocomplete, get "java -ls: cannot access 'line': No such file or directory
  "
- execute "sudo -i", enter password, get "ls: cannot access 'install_path': No such file or directory"
- type "python3 -", autocomplete, get "python3 -ls: cannot access 'line': No such file or directory"

Comment: what exactly are you trying to tell me...?

Comment: did u even read the question? its not about me grepping an alias off my alias list.

Comment: again: me apparently inappropriately grepping an alias off of my alias list has nothing to do with "unzip" not being able to autocomplete. at no point do i manually infer a grep during my call "unzip<space><tab>". get to your point. if your point is to talk down on me, youre not being helpful at all.

Comment: Well, now: it took, a while for me to grasp that there was no `=` on that  first line, i.e. it is NOT an attempt to define an alias. Sorry for the confusion. I'll delete my comments above, they're of no use.

Comment: As read, it appears as your `unzip` has a setting ($UNZIP / $UNZIPOPT - ref: man unzip) or a problem with a literal string meant to say `/tmp` but missing the initial `/`. But you also have an `ls` in there - where might that come from? What does `type -a unzip` or even `type -a unpack` tell?

Comment: @Hannu sorry for lettin ya wait; first command returns 
`unzip is /usr/bin/unzip
unzip is /bin/unzip`

whereas second command leaves me slightly confused regarding the ticks in the result:
`unpack is aliased to \`unzip'`

Comment: with that newfound command, i also found that "unzip" command does not exist in /bin

Comment: A hunch... do  you have an `unzip` file in the `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/` folder? Note: I have NO such file. (Running same as you; 20.04)

Comment: @Hannu i do not :D